# Is there a way in Indesign to link parts of a frame between documents?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Say, I have a CV. There're multiple versions of it - from the longest and the most complete down to the shorter ones, adapted for different industries or positions. The all text in any version of CV should be contained inside one single frame so it could reflow automatically from one page to another.

Is it possible to link different parts of this frame (that's divided into logical sections under different headings, for example, *Qualifications*, *Education* and etc.) to corresponding parts of a frame in another document? So if I edit the 'full' version of CV, the text of shorter ones could be updated via Links palette, for example, or in some other way?

I tried to do this with nested (anchored) frames, but it 1) makes Indesign crash upon pasting a link via Conveyor tool and 2) requires some non-obvious formatting for the anchored frame (`Space Before`/`After` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a shout for Conditional Text! You can select different paragraphs to be grouped under specific sets. Imagine that these sets are Layers that will contain different paragraphs!

[image]

Once you have created your specific sets for your shorter versions.

Then you can assign these paragraphs to these sets. And with The View Icons you can then switch off and on the sets as needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this is clear, please note that you can assign paragraphs to multiple sets also incase shorter versions share same paragraphs as well!

Comment: Wow, thanks, I should definitely try this and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hope u find it useful! Let me know if u need further help on this.